# How to retrieve a static UITableViewCell not on screen yet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with a bunch of static `UITableViewCell`s which represent menu items. The cells are all defined in the storyboard

When the `UITableView` appears, I want to set the detail text for each cell with a value for that menu item.

I have tagged all of the table cells and in `viewDidLoad`, I retrieve all of the cells with `viewWithTag:`. However, I am only able to retrieve cells that are already visible on the screen.

I understand that the static table cells aren't loaded from the NIB until it's time for them to appear on the screen.

Is there a way for force a `UITableView` to load all of the cells in the beginning?

I am thinking of using `UITableViewDelegate:tableView:cellWillAppear` to initialize the offscreen cells when they appear, but I'd rather not have separate ways of initializing the cells.

---

*Update*

This table is used as a menu to select a list to look at. I am trying to show the count of the list items. On each menu item (table cell), I set the list ID as the tag in the NIB, along with the name of the list.

**Retrieving the cell by tag**

```
- (void) setDetailLabelForList: (NSInteger)listId withString: (NSString*) string
{

    NSInteger tag = listId;
    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView viewWithTag:tag];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = string;
}
```

Another approach is to retrieve the static cells by index paths. This requires a mapping between listID and index path. However, the result is the same, because retrieving a static cell that is not yet on the screen returns nil.

**Retrieving by index path**

```
- (void) setDetailLabelForList: (NSInteger)listId withString: (NSString*) string
{
    NSString* path = [vocabListToUIMap objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:listId]];
    if (path)
    {
        NSArray* pathElements = [path componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        NSInteger sectionNum = [[pathElements objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
        NSInteger itemNum = [[pathElements objectAtIndex:1] intValue];

        NSIndexPath* path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:itemNum inSection:sectionNum];

        UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = string;
   }
}
```

EDIT: code added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by saving the setting the label on the cell using `UITableViewDelegate` `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath`. At that point, the static cell has been loaded from the NIB.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you relying on tags to determine which cells are which?  Use the `row` property of `NSIndexPath` when performing the logic in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  If you want to specify each type at compile time, you can create `UITableViewCell` subclasses for each menu type, but I wouldn't recommend this.

If you can post some of your table view code, we can look at some ways to reimplement it without `viewWithTag:`.